# How do I use a self signed cert with bitbucket client backup?

Tags: ssl, client, backup, bitbucket, self-signed

This is the answer to the question because it's not on stack overflow and it's pretty obscure but people need to know. This should work on all SSL connectors in atlassian products.

Running the v2.0 of the bitbucket-backup-client on bitbucket server 4.0 throws this error if you are using a self signed cert:

com.atlassian.bitbucket.internal.backup.client.BackupException: Bitbucket was not accessible: is the Bitbucket instance using an invalid or self-signed certificate?

Here's how to resolve it:

Test the ssl connection with SSLPoke to confirm it's a cert issue:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/KB/Unable+to+Connect+to+SSL+Services+due+to+PKIX+Path+Building+Failed

There is a link on that page to the resolution on the page that it goes to here: (command line section)

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/connecting-to-ssl-services-117455.html#ConnectingtoSSLservices-commandline

In short, Linux: Run these commands

1) Get your cert

openssl s_client -connect yourserver.com:443 < /dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > public.crt

2) Add cert to the cacerts directory which Java will use

/bin/keytool -import -alias  -keystore /jre/lib/security/cacerts -file public.crt

- I used my full server name as the  field
- default java keystore password is "changeit" if prompted

You'll also need to ensure that you put the cert it has you save into the correct cacerts directory. I had multiple so make sure that you verify which one your server is setup to use.

Hope this helps, good luck.